# SQL query - fetch last nodes from graph/tree

Tags: sql, jpa, graph, tree, nodes

I'm looking for help. I want to fetch the last node in the tree. Having a table and data in that table creates a tree structure like here:

```
                          Node 0
                          /    \ 
                  Node 1          Node 2
              /       \                   \
          Node 3       Node 4  <--       Node 5 <--
          /          
      Node 6 <--
```

Each node has an id and parentId. So Node1 has id: 1 and parentId: 0 that connects it with the upper node.

```
Node columns:
Id
parentId (upper node)
```

What I want:
So when I choose node 0, I want to "go down" and get back nodes 6, 4, and 5. And when I choose node 1 I want to fetch nodes 6 and 4. The last nodes of the structure. I don't want intermediate nodes.

I tried doing a common table expression, with .. as. But I get intermediate nodes and that's a mess in my case.
Jpa solution is also appreciated.
Thanks and good luck ;)

Comment: I did it in sql server as child,parent table  and use `CTE RECURSIVE` to get all parent with condition

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following JPA model :

```
@Entity
class Node {
@Id
long id; 

@ManyToOne
Node parent;
}
```

The leaves of the tree are the nodes not being a parent node.

If all the nodes of your model belongs to the same unique tree, the following request can be done :

```
SELECT n FROM Node n WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT p FROM Node p WHERE p.parent = n)
```

If you store several trees in your db or if you want the leaves under a specific node there is no way to build a recursive JPA query.

However, if there is not too much data in your Db, you can load all leaves (whatever node they belong to) with the same JPA request, and recursively scan each node in memory keeping those whose ancestor is the specific node limiting your scope.

BTW, if your store severeal trees in your Db, modifying the initial JPA model helps loading all the nodes of a tree with one JPA request.
Then do all kind of search in memory.

The model must be extended by adding on each node a relation to the root node :

```
@Entity
class Node {
@Id
long id; 

@ManyToOne
Node parent;

@ManyToOne
Node root;

}
```

With such a model, the complete set of nodes of a tree can be loaded with one request :

```
SELECT n FROM node WHERE p.root.id = :id_of_the_wanted_root
```